# jQuery each function with multiple selectors output in same element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors, each

Hy guys !

I would like to display (with $.each) a summary of my form in a single element, like that :

```
Lorem - 15$
Ipsum - 27$
Amet - 12$
```

But how to associate each selectors ? :
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3ykbbf7g/1/)

Actually i got this output :

```
Lorem -
15 -
Ipsum -
27 -
Amet -
12 -
```

Thank you for all ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `HTML` format is **fixed**, you can use `next` to get the next `input` value.

```
$.each($("input[name*='data']"), function() {
    $('#preview').append($(this).val() + ' - ' + $(this).next('input').val() + '$<br>');
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/3ykbbf7g/2/)

Comment: Yes it does the job ! Just curious, is that possible with multiple selectors ?

Comment: @WalkerNuss Yes, in this case multiple selector is not needed

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try this:

```
var counter = 1,
    $preview = $('#preview');

$.each($("input[name*='data'],input[name*='price']"), function() {

    $preview.append($(this).val());

    if (counter % 2 === 0) {
        $preview.append('$ <br>');
    } else {
        $preview.append(' - ');
    }

    counter++; 
});
```

In each iteration you check if you are on even, or odd item, and you can define your own ending. This is more universal solution.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3ykbbf7g/3/)

Comment: Oh yes! It does the job too! Thank you for answer ;-)